# Advanced Functional Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)$ be a strictly increasing function defined for all $x > 0$ such that $f(x) > -\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x > 0$, and $f(x) f \left( f(x) + \frac{1}{x} \right) = 1$for all $x > 0$. Find $f(1)$.

I don't know how to do this. Can someone help?

Comment: \ [ ... \ ] does not work here. Always use $

Comment: @sumi What have you tried?